# How to add a node to a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to add a new Node, to be placed at the front of a linked list. I first check to see if there are any Nodes in the current list. If there aren't any then I just use Front to create one. But if there are Nodes already then I use my else statement. But on the line Temp = new Node; I am getting an error on the word Temp saying that it is undefined. How do I define the name for a temporary Node?

```
void llist::addFront(el_t NewNum) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        Front = new Node;
        Front->Elem = NewNum;
        Rear = Front;
        Rear->Next = NULL;
        Count++;
    }
    else {
        Temp = new Node;
        Temp->Elem = NewNum;
        Temp->Next = Front;
        Front = Temp;
        Count++;

    } // comment the 2 cases
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> But on the line `Temp = new Node;` I am getting an error

Because you have to specify the type for `Temp`:

```
Node* Temp = new Node;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `Temp` variable using its type (`Node*`) so the declaration of `Temp` should look like:

```
Node* Temp = new Node;
```

This is exactly like we do with:

```
int x = 0; //we put the type of 'x' (which is 'int' in that case);
```